# Keyboard down button does not work when overflow is defined for html, body

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've encountered a peculiar problem when using a defined `overflow`.

When I use any of the following:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    // OR
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    // OR
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The down button won't scroll the page down until I click on the document. Scrolling with the mouse still works fine, though. This problem doesn't occur when I don't define an `overflow`, which is fine for what I'm doing now, but I'd still like to know why that is so.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shiazure/K552t/

Using Windows 7 SP1, browsers tested are Chrome and FF (Both most recent)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or something? Then we'll know we're all talking about the exact same setup. Also mention the browser(s) and operating system(s) this happens in. (Windows tends to scroll the currently active window; Linux the window that the mouse happens to be over).

Comment: @MrLister I added the info you asked for. Win7 SP1, Chrome & FF, and fiddle is up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no `overflow` property, there's nothing that can scroll. So that explains the difference between having an overflow or not. (Note that not specifying `overflow` means it defaults to `visible`, not `auto`. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow)).

Now you can't scroll using the down arrow because the body isn't focused when you load the page.

Solution: make sure the body has the focus. In the fiddle, this is done by adding a little Javascript

```
document.body.tabIndex = '0';
document.body.focus();
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/K552t/5/).
The second line sets the focus to the body. The first line is needed in Chrome, to make sure the body is actually focusable. Firefox needs only the second line.

You won't be able to see the difference in the fiddle itself, because the output is in a separate frame, but here is its ["show"](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/K552t/5/show) page, out of the frame, that works as advertised. Compare to your original ["show"](http://jsfiddle.net/Shiazure/K552t/show) page.